# NgAttr value initially empty when containing mustache directive in AngularDart

Tags: attributes, dart, angular-dart

Chapter 3 of the [AngularDart tutorial](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/05-ch03-component.html) defines a `rating` `@NgComponent` (see excerpt below), that is used in `index.html` like this:

```html
<rating max-rating="5" rating="ctrl.selectedRecipe.rating"></rating>
```

In that chapter it is also suggested that that the `max-rating` `@NgAttr` can be set via a `{{...}}` like this:

```html
<rating max-rating="{{ctrl.max}}" rating="ctrl.selectedRecipe.rating"></rating>
```

In the `RecipeController` I have simply declared:

```dart
 int max = 5;
```

If I add `print("maxRating('$value')")` at the top of the component's `maxRating()` setter body (see below), then in running the app I get the following output:

```
maxRating('')  // printed 7 times
maxRating('5') // printed 7 times
```

**Questions: Why is the value initially empty?**  I assume that it is because the interpolation has not been done yet, **but then why is the setter called at all before the value is "ready"?**

---

Excerpt of `RatingComponent` class definition:

```dart
@NgComponent(
selector: 'rating', ...
publishAs: 'cmp'
)
class RatingComponent {
  ...

  @NgTwoWay('rating')
  int rating;

  @NgAttr('max-rating')
  set maxRating(String value) {
    var count = value == null ? 5 : int.parse(value);
    stars = new List.generate(count, (i) => i+1);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running the latest dart and have latest angular.dart? I just tried running as you described and see no empty output, just proper values.

Comment: @markovuksanovic. Yes: Dart Editor version 1.1.1.release (STABLE) with angular version: "0.9.6". Are you running it in Dartium?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Dart version AngularDart 0.9.6 on dart 1.1.1. Are you sure you don't have any other changes in your code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, angular dart is very eager in applying values. As soon as angular is running it starts applying values, I guess to provide a feel of responsiveness. 
I've been bitten by this too and had to write more than one workaround for not yet initialized values.

The setter and getters are called by the binding mechanism to stabilize the values, as some values may depend on each other and the mechanism "brute forces" this by just setting and getting values multiple times (7 by default, IIRC).